# Expected number of non-singleton balls (balls and bins)

Tags: probability

If we throw $m$ balls into $n$ bins independently and uniformly at random, what is the expected number of balls that are in a bin containing at least one other ball?

My reasoning for this was that for a particular ball, the probability that some other ball falls in the same bin is $1 - P[$No other ball falls in the same bin$] = 1 - (1 - \frac1n)^{m-1}$. Thus the expected number of balls in a bin with at least 1 other ball (by independence and linearity of expectation) is $m(1 - (1 - \frac1n)^{m-1})$.

However, I am simulating this in Python and am getting a large average error between the simulated and expected value over 1000 trials (with $m = 20$, $n = 35$). Is the above recurrence incorrect, or is my simulation probably incorrect? Might it have anything to do with the fact that the expected value is real-valued while the simulation produces integer values?

Comment: The expression for the expectation is correct. The fact that any particular result of throwing $20$ balls results in an integer should not be relevant, the average of $1000$ counts will almost certainly not be an integer.

Comment: Turns out, I had a bug in my program. I was raising the outer parenthetical expression to the $m-1$ instead of the inner one. Darn parentheses :)

Comment: The expectation calculation was totally clear. Of course, changing wording slightly changes the answer a lot, as in mean number of bins with more than one occupant.